# creating array with references duplicates elements

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to pass array values by reference in order to use `call_user_func_array` and i keep getting duplicate values for the elements set in the `foreach` loop. how can i fix this?

```
foreach($non_empty_fields as $key => $value){
    $values_array[] = &$value;
}
unset ($value);
$values_array[] = &$user_id;        
print_r($non_empty_fields);
print_r($values_array);
```

prints out

```
Array
(
    [gender] => female
    [device_id] => 1213423489ydasxas98y76
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1213423489ydasxas98y76
    [1] => 1213423489ydasxas98y76
    [2] => 35
)
```

Comment: What result are you trying to get?

Comment: @ialarmedalien `[0] => female`
    `[1] => 1213423489ydasxas98y76`
    `[2] => 35` just without duplicates

Comment: You've got an array here, there can't be any values passed by reference in array. Array itself can be passed by reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you're making a reference to `$value` in your `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($non_empty_fields as $key => $value){
    $values_array[] = &$value;
}
```

You need to make the reference to the **actual value** in `$non_empty_fields`:

```
foreach($non_empty_fields as $key => $value){
    $values_array[] = &$non_empty_fields[$key];
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => female
    [1] => 1213423489ydasxas98y76
    [2] => 35
)
```

It's well worth reading through the [PHP documentation on references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php), and the examples, because they don't always act in an intuitive manner (at least IMHO!).

Comment: Or foreach($non_empty_fields as &$value){ $values_array[] = $value; } unset($value);

Answer (score 0):

Try to reference the array items like:

```
$non_empty_fields = array('gender' => 'female', 'device_id' => '1213...');

foreach($non_empty_fields as $key => $value) {
   $values_array[] = &$non_empty_fields[$key];
}
```

`print_r($values_array)` returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => female
    [1] => 1213...
)
```

Comment: Note that the OP says "I'm trying to pass array values by reference".